# Finding Surface Integral of a plane inside a half cylinder and Flux of part of a paraboloid (2 Problems)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I am stuck/unsure about two problems out of my homework (my professor grades homework in my class) and I can't afford to lose points on my final homework assignment. I tried going to the tutoring center at my college but there we no multi-variable calculus tutors available, now I am turning to you guys to ask you to please help me out, pretty please :)!

I have solved the problems and shown my work, but I just need someone to check if they are correct or not because I don't want to lose points on homework. If they are wrong can you please explain to me what I did wrong as well.

Here are the two questions along with my work: [http://imgur.com/a/Js8KL](https://imgur.com/a/Js8KL)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work looks fine to me.

For the second exercise: I assume they mean the 'open' paraboloid so without the closing cap of $z=1$. I would interpret the question this way and it is also how you solved it.

A small typo: when substituting $z=x^2+y^2$ into $\vec F$, you forgot the square of the $z$-component:
$$\vec F = \langle x^2 , y^2 , z^\color{blue}{2}\rangle= \langle x^2 , y^2 , (x^2+y^2)^\color{red}{2}\rangle $$
You also omitted the differential elements before switching to polar coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I've fixed the typo. I have a bad habit of forgetting to write the differential elements, I sometimes get too lazy :P.

Comment: You're welcome, but you shouldn't be lazy if you don't want to "lose points" ;-).